# How to minimise the maximum value of a variable given an equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation 
    $$x + y + z = n$$
I want to minimize the $\max\{x,y,z\}$.

From my intuition, it is clear that the maximum will be minimized when $x=y=z$. But how can I prove it mathematically?

Comment: If you have $\max\{x,y,z\} \lt \frac{n}{3}$ then what will happen? Will they still be able to sum up to $n/3$?

Comment: Note that there is an implicit assumption here that $x, y, z$ are real numbers. If $x, y, z$ are integers then $x=y=z=\frac{n}{3}$ may not be feasible - for example, if $n=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \max_k x_k$ is convex, and the set $F = \{ x | \sum_k x_k = n \}$ is convex.

Note that $f(x) = f(Px)$ for any permutation $P$ (and $P F = F$).

Let ${\cal P}$ be the set of permutations of the indices of $x$.

Since $f$ is convex, we have
$f( {1 \over |{\cal P}|}\sum_{P \in {\cal P}} Px ) = f(\bar{x}) \le {1 \over |{\cal P}|} \sum_{P \in {\cal P}} f(Px) = f(x)$, where
$\bar{x} = {1 \over |{\cal P}|}\sum_{P \in {\cal P}} Px = ({1 \over n}\sum_k x_k) (1,...,1)$.

Since $\sum_k x_k = n$, we see that $f$ is minimised on $F$ at $(1,...,1)$.

**Simpler approach**:

The pigeon hole principle shows that if $x \in F$, then there is some $k$ such that $x_k \ge 1$. Hence $f(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \in F$. Since
$f((1,...,1)) = 1$, we see that $(1,...,1)$ is a (the) minimiser of $f$
on $F$.

Comment: What do you mean by PF=F?

Comment: It means that if $x \in F$ then $Px \in F$ (and vice versa). It is just to show that $f \circ P$ is well defined. I added a simpler two line proof.

Comment: (1,...,1) means that all xk=1 for minimum?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$